# GCC warns when passing typed pointer to a function receiving void **

Tags: c, gcc

In a C code, I passed a `LJ_6_12_t **` to a function accepting a `void **` argument, but received a `-Wincompatible-pointer-types` warning along with the following "note" when compiling:

> note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘LJ_6_12_t ** {aka struct  **}’

I think with a typecast the warning would disappear, but why does it happen in the first place? Shouldn't a `void *` variable accept any kind of pointer?

Answer (score 1):

> *Shouldn't a `void *` variable accept any kind of pointer?*

Yes it should and will, but you pass to a `void**`, which is not the same as a `void*`.

Comment: They are different. But I don't understand why the compiler doesn't generalize the rule.

Comment: @Arham: Which rule?